# What is this shrub with star-like off-white flowers?

Tags: identification, shrubs

Zone 7. Growing in a neglected area. It looks it needs support, but nevertheless 8 ft high. Habit is just a huge pile of branches and leaves. It looks invasive to me. Didn't notice any bee, didn't sense any fragrance. Flowers 1in diameter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Saying “Zone 7” is not really helpful. Please see [this meta post for details](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872/for-id-questions-why-should-i-tell-where-in-the-world-a-plant-is-growing).

Comment: "Flowers 1in diameter." 1 what? 1 centimeter? 1 foot? 1 mile?

Comment: 1 inch...................

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a Clematis, Clematis vitalba. It's the one that pops up in hedgerows and the like quite naturally without anyone ever planting it. It has the common name of Traveller's Joy, supposedly because travellers on the road in summer would come across it and be pleased to see it. Also sometimes known as Old Man's Beard, so named for its fluffy seedheads. It usually scrambles over or up anything nearby, but if there's nothing for it to cling to, it makes a heap, clinging to bits of itself instead. It seeds prolifically (the seed heads are quite attractive) and the seed is spread by the wind, which is why it manages to pop up unbidden, more info here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clematis_vitalba

Comment: Looks a lot like my Clematis montanaensis which is definitely invasive  Most blooms are 20' + high when it can get to a tree.

Comment: @blacksmith Clematis montanaensis does not exist - can you clarify on the name please?

Comment: @Bamboo Either the Clematis Montana, Clematis Texensis or (if at all possible) a cross between the two? Since there's a distinct lack of pink in the flower, I'd go with the Montana.

Comment: @Mast - the clematis in the image posted above is certainly not any kind of montana variety - those flower much earlier in the year anyway, and the flowers are nothing like those pictured.- texensis flower later and the flower shape is completely different from either montana or vitalba

Comment: It is blooming now ( Aug 4, E . TX ) , vines are very similar, cluster of white flowers are similar from a distance, but have 4 petals. Some perfume. The are local natives , but I suppose they could have been introduced.